# QGIS failure in PostGIS connection: "ident authentication failed for user"

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am trying to use the 'ident' authentication of for local PostGIS (2.5) server, so that each user can connect to his/her account without having to provide password.

The local connection (to `127.0.0.1`) worked if I use `trust` in `/etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf`:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

, but fails when `trust` is replaced with `ident` and if connection is made from QGIS (3.8.1).

```
ident authentication failed for user
```

The strange thing is that I can connect successfully (with `ident` authentication) without giving user names or password, both from the command line client `psql` and from `pyscopg2` using python. But QGIS3 connection fails.

From documentation:

> ident
>
> Obtain the operating system user name of the client by contacting the
>   ident server on the client and check if it matches the requested
>   database user name. Ident authentication can only be used on TCP/IP
>   connections. When specified for local connections, peer authentication
>   will be used instead. See Section 19.3.5 for details.
>
> peer
>
> Obtain the client's operating system user name from the operating
>   system and check if it matches the requested database user name. This
>   is only available for local connections. See Section 19.3.6 for
>   details.

*Is this a bug in QGIS? Or am I missing something in the QGIS or PostGIS configuration?*

*How can I get `ident` working for QGIS?*

Note: I googled the issue, some suggest using other authentication method like `md5`. But I specifically need to `ident` behavior for multiple users. `md5` requires password, and `trust` is not secure. I need each user to access his/her own database without password, without allowing access to any other databases.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is only available on your machine you will need to use your public ip for other users to connect to that database.

Comment: instead of 127.0.0.1/32 (your localhost for IPv4) or ::1 (your localhost for IPv6), have you ever try to change it into your LAN network like 192.168.0.1/16 or 172.16.0.1/12 or 10.0.0.1/8  to allow anyone in your LAN to play and mess with your DB?

Comment: @Kampau Ocu. I haven't and do not intend to allow network access from other machines.

Answer (score 3):

This [ticket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user-unable-to-connect-to-postgresql-779171564.html) explains the issue, you need to use trust for QGis to work as it is explicitly setting the username in the connection.

> By default PostgreSQL uses IDENT-based authentication and this will never allow you to login via -U and -W options. Allow username and password based authentication from your application by applying 'trust' as the authentication method for the JIRA database user. You can do this by modifying the pg_hba.conf file.

So you will either need to use `trust` or set up passwords (`MD5`) or other authentication system.